# Jwt token generated during login cannot be validated when i try to get user profile

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, bearer-token, express-jwt

I'm trying to validate the user once he logs in using a JWT token, whereby I use the token to validate other routes like getting the user profile or updating the user profile. Once the token is generated and use postman to send the request the response i'm getting is user cannot be validated hence no data

**Here is my auth middleware**

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AuthPayload } from '../dto/Auth.dto';
import { validateSignature } from '../utility';

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: AuthPayload;
        }
    }
}

export const Authenticate = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const signature = await validateSignature(req);

    if (signature) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.json({ message: 'user not authorised' });
    }
};
```

**This is how verify the token generated**

```
export const validateSignature = async (req: Request) => {
    const signature = req.get('Authorization');

    if (signature) {
        try {
            const payload = jwt.verify(signature.split(' ')[1], JWT_SECRET) as AuthPayload;
            req.user = payload;
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false
};
```

**Then i use the middleware to restrict access to the below routes**

```
router.use(Authenticate)

router.get("/profile" ,GetVendorProfile);
```

Comment: So probably the function `validateSignature()`returned false. But in the function, you do a `catch (error) {  return false;`, without logging the actual error. Please log that error and update the question with the actual error.

Comment: On putting the console ,it performs as required  io ,it updates and get the user profile as expected